# How to solve Unmet peer dependency when I already have higher package versions directly installed?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

warnings:

> ```
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.3.1
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.3.1
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.2
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.27
> └── zone.js@0.7.8
> ```

---

npm WARN @angular/core@2.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/http@2.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/router@3.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.2.0 but none was installed.

npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.2.0 but none was installed.

npm WARN less-loader@2.2.3 requires a peer of less@^2.3.1 but none was installed.

npm WARN script-ext-html-webpack-plugin@1.7.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.2.0 but none was installed.

---

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "yo-ng2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Angular 2 Proj",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript",
    "ngrx"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/orizens/echoes-ng2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "2.2.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "3.2.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.28",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.3.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "1.0.3",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "ngrx-action-creator-factory": "0.0.1",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^0.1.5",
    "node-sass": "4.1.1",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.0",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "2.1.5",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.1",
    "uid": "0.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.11",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/orizens/echoes-ng2.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/orizens/echoes-ng2/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```