# npm install fails when a peer dependency with higher version already installed

Tags: node.js, npm-install

How do I install a package with a dependency to a package with lower version of another package that is already installed?

for example,

```
.
`-- mypackage
    `-- node_modules
        |-- modulea
        |   |-- @1.8.4
        |   `-- moduleb
        |       |-- @1.1.2
        |       `-- modulec
        |           `-- @^0.2.4 <======= newer version
        `-- moduled
            |-- @3.4.1
            `-- modulec
            |  `-- @^0.1.6 <===== older version
            `-- modulee
                `-- @^0.1.9
```

In the above case, my package is dependent on `module-a` and `module-d`. Both dependents on `module-c`. But when installing `module-d` npm ERR with `Conflicting peer dependency`.

I know we can do `--legacy-peer-deps`, but would it discard installing `module-e` as well?
Is there a way to tell npm not to install `module-c` when installing `module-d`; something like `npm install module-d --skip-peer-deps module-c`

This is almost similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453546/npm-packages-dependency-requires-lower-version-than-the-wanted-version), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260161/how-to-solve-unmet-peer-dependency-when-i-already-have-higher-package-versions-d) but no answer in there either.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

remove node-modules folder and use yarn.
Yarn solve automatically this dependencies problems

install yarn: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

than instead of `npm install`, run `yarn`